# Power-Pivot:500 Internal Server Error

Tags: powerpivot, powerview

I am importing the ssrs report from .automsvc extension and I am facing the below issue as .Can any one help me how can I solve this issue

Tablix1: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: A 500 error should wind up in the SSRS logs; perhaps start by looking there and see if you can find anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any date columns delete them from the SSRS report and see if the PowerPivot connection works.  You may need to play with formatting if you want to add the columns back.  Trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, took me a bit to find, but the issue is simple and also stupid. Power Pivot has issues with importing "Calculated Fields" - But I think these are Sharepoint created and might still work with Infopath created Calculated fields, hope this helps someone. Once I removed the calculated fields I stopped getting this error immediately.